Detect two-finger swipe gesture along with view's content interactions
I'm applying this function as a modifier to all of the SwiftUI views I want to monitor the fact of using two fingers swipe gesture.
func onTwoTouchSwipe(direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction,
                     onSwipe: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
    self.modifier(
        MultipleTouchSwipeView(
            numberOfTouchesRequired: 2,
            direction: direction,
            onSwipe: onSwipe
        )
    )
}

private struct MultipleTouchSwipeView: ViewModifier {
    let numberOfTouchesRequired: Int
    let direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction
    let onSwipe: () -> ()
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            
            SwipeableViewRepresentable(numberOfTouchesRequired: numberOfTouchesRequired,
                                       direction: direction) { _ in
                onSwipe()
            }
        }
    }
}

The logic lays inside the structure below
private struct SwipeableViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let numberOfTouchesRequired: Int
    let direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction
    let onSwipe: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void

    typealias UIViewType = UIView

    func makeCoordinator() -> SwipeCoordinator {
        SwipeCoordinator(onSwipe: self.onSwipe)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        
        let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                       action: #selector(SwipeCoordinator.handleSwipe(sender:)))
        swipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = numberOfTouchesRequired
        swipeRecognizer.direction = direction
       
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}

    class SwipeCoordinator {
        let onSwipe: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void

        init(onSwipe: @escaping (UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void) {
            self.onSwipe = onSwipe
        }

        @objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            self.onSwipe(sender)
        }
    }
}

The problem is inside MultipleTouchSwipeView's body. I tried implementing it several ways. The example above (ZStack) disables interactions of contents' elements (for examply does not allow ScrollView to scroll or buttons to click)
Using .overlay does exactly the same:
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.overlay {
        SwipeableViewRepresentable(numberOfTouchesRequired: numberOfTouchesRequired,
                                   direction: direction,
                                   toExecuteBeforeSwipe: toExecuteBeforeSwipe,
                                   toExecuteAfterSwipe: toExecuteAfterSwipe) { _ in
            onSwipe()
        }
    }
}

Whereas using .background (below) does not allow to recognize gestures (because view's content has higher priority for allowing user interaction than gesture recognizer view)
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.background {
        SwipeableViewRepresentable(numberOfTouchesRequired: numberOfTouchesRequired,
                                   direction: direction,
                                   toExecuteBeforeSwipe: toExecuteBeforeSwipe,
                                   toExecuteAfterSwipe: toExecuteAfterSwipe) { _ in
            onSwipe()
        }
    }
}

I tried experimenting with .allowHitTesting but with no success.
Is there any way to allow interacting with content along with two fingers swipe recognition?
